# Integrating WhatsAPI/Yowsup into Android

Tags: android, chat, whatsapp, yowsup

I am new to Android and aim to build a group chat, and peer to peer chat feature in my app. I have researched and read about WhatsAPI and Yowsup, as they seem to be promising, but do not see any implementation to Android.

Is anyone familiar with adding WhatsApp or Yowsup to their Android applications to enable chat and group chats successfully?

Answer (score 1):

WhatsAPI and Yowsup are non-Android based programs WhatsAPI(PHP) and Yowsup (python)

From an overview I think it will be impossible to have it on Android native.. maybe with phoneGap